# React-Native: Listview not scrolling to bottom of screen in IOS only

Tags: android, listview, react-native, scrollview, react-native-ios

ListView scrolling working perfect on Android but on IOS when i try to scroll down from bottom of screen it is not recognising touch and not scrolling down while scrolling from top of listView is working. Below is code snippet.

```
render()
{
    return(
        <View style={styles.MainContainerViewCamp}>
            <View>
                <View>
                    <TextInput />
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style = {{ flex:1 }}>
                <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                    <ListView
                        ...
                        renderRow {(rowData) =>
                            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            </View>
                        }
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </View> 
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    MainContainerViewCamp: 
    {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 20,
        padding: 5,
    },

 });
```

I have applied {flex:1} to the root views and all other possible solutions like adding {flex:1} or {height} to listView/ScrollView. But nothing is working. Please help.

Edited: I am adding entire code for better understanding. One more thing to know that my datasource has more than 200 entries.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, TextInput,Keyboard,TouchableWithoutFeedback, ActivityIndicator, Switch, ListView, Text, View, 
    Alert, Platform, TouchableHighlight, Image, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

    import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
    import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
    import EntypoIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
    import FoundationIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Foundation';

    import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

    //import { add_campaign } from './add_campaign';

    class view_camp extends Component {


    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'View Campaigns',
        headerLeft : null,
    };

    listViewRef;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        text: '',
        stat: '',
        isPopupMenu : false,
        menu_camp_id : '',
        menu_status : '',
        menu_camp_name : '',
        enableScrollViewScroll : true,
        }
        this.setEnableScrollViewScroll = this.setEnableScrollViewScroll.bind(this);
        this.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture = this.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture.bind(this);
        this.arrayholder = [];
    }

    setEnableScrollViewScroll(value) {
        // we need to manually handle the ScrollView scrollEnabled to allow child ListView to scroll in there parent
        this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: value });
    }

    onStartShouldSetResponderCapture() {
        // when there is scroll in the result list - we set the parent's ScrollView scrollEnabled to false
        // so the child ListView can handle the scroll events
        this.props.setEnableScrollViewScroll(false);

        // if the scroll is out of the ListView we reset the parent's ScrollView scrollEnabled to true
        if (this.listViewRef.scrollProperties.offset === 0 && this.state.enableScrollViewScroll === false) {
        this.setEnableScrollViewScroll(true);
        }
    }



    componentDidMount() { 
        const base64 = require('base-64');
        return fetch('APIURL', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": "Basic " + base64.encode("demo:QZMW]C")
        }
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => { 
            let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
            this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),
            }, function () {
            this.arrayholder = responseJson;
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    _onSearchFilterFunction(text) {
        const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function (item) {
        const itemData = item.Ad_name.toUpperCase()
        const textData = text.toUpperCase()
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
        })
        this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newData),
        text: text
        })
    }

    _onPressButton = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Third', { ClientId: this.props.navigation.state.params.ClientId });
    }


    ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
        <View
            style={{
            height: .5,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#000",

            }}
        />
        );
    }

    RenderListViewHeader = () => {

        var header = (

        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} >
            <ScrollView horizontal={true}>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Ad Name</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Ad Type</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >CPR</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >CPM</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Budget</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Daily Budget</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Total Budget Spent</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Imps</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Recalls</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Correct Recalls</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Clicks</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Start Date</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >End Date</Text>

            <Text style={styles.stickyTextViewContainer} >Status</Text>

            {/* <Text style={styles.stickyActionTextViewContainer} >Action</Text> */}

            </ScrollView>
        </View>

        );

        return header;
    };

    getMenuParams = (camp_id,status,camp_name) => 
    {
        //console.log("camp_id: "+camp_id +" status: "+status+" camp_name: "+camp_name);
        this.setState({
        isPopupMenu : true,
        menu_camp_id : camp_id,
        menu_status : status,
        menu_camp_name : camp_name
        });
        //console.log("ispopupmenu: "+this.state.isPopupMenu+" menu_camp_id: "+this.state.menu_camp_id +" menu_status: "+this.state.menu_status+" menu_camp_name: "+this.state.menu_camp_name);
    }  

    toggleCancel = () => 
    { 
        this.setState({
        isPopupMenu:false,
        });
    }

    setMenuRef = ref => { 
        this._menu = ref;
        this.showMenu();
    };

    hideMenu = () => {
        this._menu.hide();
    };

    showMenu = () => { //console.log("start");
        this._menu.show();
        //console.log("end");
    };

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        //const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        );
        }

        return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainerViewCamp} 
         // when scrolling the parent scroll view we reset the enableScroll to true
            onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() =>{this.setEnableScrollViewScroll(true);}}
            >

            <Text style={{ padding: 5, fontSize: 35, backgroundColor: '#00BCD4' }}>All Campaigns</Text>
            <View style={styles.OuterSectionStyle}>
            <View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon name='search' style={styles.icon} />
                <TextInput
                onChangeText={(text) => this._onSearchFilterFunction(text)}
                value={this.state.text}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                placeholder="Search Here"
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.SubmitButtonStyle}
                activeOpacity={.5}
                onPress={this._onPressButton}>
                <MaterialIcon name='add-box' style={styles.icon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

            <ScrollView horizontal={true} 
            // enable ScrollView scroll according to state's value
            scrollEnabled = {this.state.enableScrollViewScroll} 
            >

            <ListView

                onRef={(ref) => this.listViewRef = ref}

                onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={this.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture}

                enableEmptySections={true}

                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

                stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}

                renderHeader={this.RenderListViewHeader}

                renderSeparator={this.ListViewItemSeparator}

                renderRow={(rowData) =>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer}> {rowData.Ad_name} </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>


                    {/* <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Ad_name}</Text> */}

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Ad_type}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.CPR}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.CPM}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Budget}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Daily_budget}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Total_budget_spent}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Imps}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Recalls}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Correct_recalls}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >                
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Clicks}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.Start_date}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        //style={styles.showMenuContainer}
                        activeOpacity={.5}
                        onPress={this.getMenuParams.bind(this,rowData.campaign_id,rowData.Status,rowData.Ad_name)}
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textViewContainer} >{rowData.End_date}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    {rowData.Status == '0' ?
                    <View style={styles.SwitchOuterSectionStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.textWithSwitch}>
                        Inactive </Text>
                        <Switch
                        onValueChange={this.onStatusButtonPressed.bind(this, rowData.Status, rowData.campaign_id)}
                        value={false} />
                    </View>

                    :
                    <View style={styles.SwitchOuterSectionStyle}>
                        <Text style={styles.textWithSwitch}>
                        Active </Text>
                        <Switch
                        onValueChange={this.onStatusButtonPressed.bind(this, rowData.Status, rowData.campaign_id)}
                        value={true} />
                    </View>}
                    </View>
                }
            />
            </ScrollView>
            </View>
            </View>



        );
    }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    MainContainerViewCamp: {

        // Setting up View inside content in Vertically center.
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 20,
        padding: 5,
    },

    textViewContainer: {

        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        padding: 7,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#87ceeb',
        fontSize: 13,
        width: 150,
    },
    stickyTextViewContainer: {

        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        padding: 7,
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#87ceeb',
        fontSize: 13,
        width: 150,
        marginBottom: 3,
    },

    stickyActionTextViewContainer: {

        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        padding: 7,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: 45,
        backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#87ceeb',
        fontSize: 13,
        width: 550,
    },
    textWithSwitch: {

        fontSize: 13,
    },
    imageClass: {
        height: 40,
        width: 40,
        marginLeft: 25,
        borderRadius: 7,
    },
    SubmitButtonStyle: {

        marginTop: 10,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginBottom: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#D6EAF8',
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#fff'
    },

    TextStyle: {
        color: '#fff',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },

    icon: {
        fontSize: 30,
        padding: 5
    },
    TextInputStyleClass: {

        textAlign: 'center',
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#009688',
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"

    },
        OuterSectionStyle: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        margin: 10,
        height: 50,

        },
    SwitchOuterSectionStyle: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        padding: 7,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: 150,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#87ceeb',
    },
    IconOuterSectionStyle: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        padding: 7,
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: 550,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#87ceeb',
    },
    SectionStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: .5,
        borderColor: '#000',
        height: 40,
        width: 220,
        borderRadius: 5,
        margin: 10
    },
    });

    module.exports = view_camp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is not scrolling probably according to this [React Native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1966).

The following works very well on IOS and Android both, scrolls the ListView if the touch is on List and else it scrolls the ScrollView.

Try change your code as following:

```
class MainContainerViewCamp extends React.Component {

  listViewRef; // hold list view reference 

  constructor() {
    this.state={ enableScrollViewScroll: true};

    this.setEnableScrollViewScroll = this.setEnableScrollViewScroll.bind(this);
    this.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture = this.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture.bind(this);
  }

  setEnableScrollViewScroll(value) {
    // we need to manually handle the ScrollView scrollEnabled to allow child ListView to scroll in there parent
    this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: value });
  }

  onStartShouldSetResponderCapture() {
    // when there is scroll in the result list - we set the parent's ScrollView scrollEnabled to false
    // so the child ListView can handle the scroll events
    this.props.setEnableScrollViewScroll(false);

    // if the scroll is out of the ListView we reset the parent's ScrollView scrollEnabled to true
    if (this.listViewRef.scrollProperties.offset === 0 && this.state.enableScrollViewScroll === false) {
      this.setEnableScrollViewScroll(true);
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <View style = {{ flex:1 }}
       // when scrolling the parent scroll view we reset the enableScroll to true
       onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() =>{this.setEnableScrollViewScroll(true);}>
       <ScrollView
         horizontal={true}
         // enable ScrollView scroll according to state's value
         scrollEnabled={this.state.enableScrollViewScroll}
         >
         <ListView
           ...
           onRef={(ref) => this.listViewRef = ref}
           onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={this.onStartShouldSetResponderCapture}
           renderRow {(rowData) =>
             <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                </View>
           }
          />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: still not working on IOS.. Issue is If i scroll down from lower half of listview it doesn't work but if i scroll down from top half of listview it scrolls down.